# high z-index in low z-index - special navigation bar

Tags: html, css, position, z-index, fixed

I'm try to do a special navigation-bar.

I will show it in pictures:
this on scrollbar on top
[image: on scrollbar on top]

and this on scrollbar down:
[image: this on scrollbar down]

So I tried to do header with `position: fixed` and `z-index: 1`.

inside nav with `z-index` high(1000) and
 the right block  with `z-index` high(1000)
 and the content have `z-index: 2` and `position: relative`.

and it didn't worked :/

**and important thing is that I need the upload `div` will be in the header
and will be higher (in `z-index`) from content

I will try to show you in code:

```css
header {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: blue;

}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#upload {
  background-color: green;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#content {
  position: realative;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav></nav>
  <div id="upload">
  </div>

</header>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

thank you,and I'm sorry about my english !!

Comment: Both navbars or whatever you wanna call them have to be fixed. Then the one over all give it a z-index 100 and the one under everything give it a -100 z index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to move the `nav` out of the `header` for the `#content` `z-index` to work and need to align `nav` with fixed positioning or by giving `margin`

```css
header {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#upload {
  background-color: green;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<nav>
  <div id="upload"></div>
</nav>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: thier is no way to do that when #upload div and nav inside the header ?

Comment: only option is you can put the content `div` inside header